# Rubymine never finishes test process with spring + minitest while testing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spring, rubymine, minitest

I can't seem to get my tests in Rubymine to complete. The bar runs all the way to the last test but hangs there even after output says that call test passed. I have to stop the process entirely and when I do the bar finishes and says all tests pass, I get the notification as if it ran correctly but I had to interrupt the process. I'm using spring as the preloader for the tests. The previous version of RM had the same issue.

Using RM 2016.1, Ruby 2.2.3, Rails 4.1.14, Minitest 5.8.4, Minitest-reporters 1.1.7. Spring 1.6.3

Comment: What happens when you run the tests from the command-line? IDE like Rubymine are nice, but they isolate you from the actual code and tests. When they encounter something unexpected they can act up leaving you wondering what happened.

Comment: I agree with the  above comment. I use Rubymine as well and I'd recommend testing from your native shell for the same reasons.